# Scheme Loop Through a List

Tags: scheme

How would I loop this list in scheme?

```
(define test-document '(
                    ((h e l l o))
                    ((t h i s)(i s)(t e s t))
                    ))
```

What I tried it only showed the first column.

Comment: What do you mean by "loop this list"?

Comment: Being able to access each word in the list in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a list of lists of lists:

```
(define test-document '(((h e l l o)) ((t h i s) (i s) (t e s t))))
```

To loop over its elements you must create a loop of a loop of a loop. To do so we can use `map` and `curry` as follows:

```
(map (curry map (curry map
        (compose string->symbol string-upcase symbol->string)))
    test-document)
```

This produces the following output:

```
(((H E L L O)) ((T H I S) (I S) (T E S T)))
```

If your Scheme interpreter doesn't have a built-in `curry` function then you can define one as follows:

```
(define (curry func . args)
    (lambda x (apply func (append args x))))
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: It says curry is undefined

Comment: Which scheme interpreter are you using? The `curry` function is available in `mzscheme`. Anyway I updated my answer with an implementation of `curry`.

Answer (score 3):

`car` and `cdr` family of functions are your friends to navigate lists. Here are some examples.

```
(define test-document '(
                    ((h e l l o))
                    ((t h i s)(i s)(t e s t))
                    ))

(car test-document)  ;; `((h e l l o))
(caar test-document)  ;; `(h e l l o)
(cadr test-document) ;; `((t h i s) (i s) (t e s t))
(car (cadr test-document) ;; `(t h i s)
(cadr (cadr test-document) ;; `(i s)
(caddr (cadr test-document) ;; `(test )
```

Define a function that will walk the list and call a function for each item that is not a list.

```
(define (walk-list lst fun)
   (if (not (list? lst))
      (fun lst)
      (if (not (null? lst))
         (begin
            (walk-list (car lst) fun)
            (walk-list (cdr lst) fun)))))
```

Call it to print each item.

```
(walk-list test-document print)
```

Comment: But what if you don't know the size of the document.

Comment: @PhilipRego I added some more content to my answer to illustrate how you can walk a list and do something with the items in it.

Comment: How do I get it to print the words without parethesis. it gets the words as a list but i cant do anything with it cause it has the dumb pareteses around them 
(define (walk-list lst fun)
   (if (not (equal? (car lst) '()))
      (fun lst)
      (if (not (null? lst))
         (begin
            (walk-list (car lst) fun)
            (walk-list (cdr lst) fun)))))
(walk-list test-document display)

Answer (score 1):

Were you thinking of something like this?

```
(define (walk-list lst)
  (define (sub-walk lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (let ((x (car lst)))
          (if (list? x)
              (cons (sub-walk x) (sub-walk (cdr lst)))
              (apply string-append (map symbol->string lst))))))
  (flatten (sub-walk lst)))
```

then

```
(walk-list test-document)
=> '("hello" "this" "is" "test")
```

which you can process using the usual suspects (`map`, `filter`, ...).

If your Scheme has no `flatten` procedure, you can use this one:

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (reverse
   (let loop ((lst lst) (res null))
     (if (null? lst)
         res
         (let ((c (car lst)))
           (loop (cdr lst) (if (pair? c) (loop c res) (cons c res))))))))
```

Comment: I don't have the function flatten

Comment: That's why I put one in my answer!